# How do I set the TypeScript compiler version for an ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 project in Visual Studio 2015 RC?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, typescript1.5

So I'm now at my witts end with this one.  As the question in the title asks, I'm trying to set the tsc version for a sample ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 project.  I'm using Visual Studio 2015 RC and I want to compile TypeScript using version 1.5 Beta that was recently released.  In VS 2013, this was an option page in the project properties.  I thought there would be some magic project.json value I could set, but nope.  If I could even turn off the compilation (version 1.4) and use a Gulp task, even that would I could count as progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this in ASP.NET 5 natively. This is something you should handle inside gulp or grunt tasks. See [this sample grunt task](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/f0998dffbc5e6846515787eb931bd979753efd58/src/MusicStore.Spa/grunt/typescript.json) for typescript. It is based on [the dependency you have](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/f0998dffbc5e6846515787eb931bd979753efd58/src/MusicStore.Spa/package.json#L16) for grunt typescript plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the response @tugberk.  I thought I was going crazy.  Gulp build step it is.