# Where is the TypeScript Tools version set in an ASP.NET 5 Project?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm working with a *default* ASP.NET 5 Web project template and trying to determine how to dictate the TypeScript tools and ultimately compiler version for my application.

I'm ***not*** yet using `Gulp` so this post's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116920/how-do-i-set-the-typescript-compiler-version-for-an-asp-net-5-mvc-6-project-in-v) does not seem to hold water. The reason being, my app even without Gulp has to be told which TypeScript compiler to use. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566690/typescript-version-in-asp-net-5-project) as well wasn't about finding the version but rather using features not yet supported.

In VSNET 2013, the TypeScript tools version and compiler targeted was set in the project's properties:

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.7</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

I believe it to be an option of the `compilerOptions` section of my `tsconfig.json` file. However I get no intellisense for `version` and it appears the documentation is sparse. This [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options) states it just emits the compiler's version but doesn't allow specifying it.

I currently have version 1.6 and 1.7 installed on my machine. If there is a need for me to dictate a specific compiler version, how do I set that in an ASP.NET 5 web template? Again the answer isn't immediately to use Gulp because it builds and compiles my `.ts` files as is now, so something is dictating the compiler being used.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Typescript Tools. What do you do with it that you can't do with the built in Typescript in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Can you please improve this question by clarifying exactly what you mean by ' I get no intellisense for version'.   Also this sentence "This link states it just emits the compiler's version but doesn't allow specifying it."  - I don't understand. *what* is the thing that you are you trying to say emits the compilers version? Also this question in the OP doesn't really make sense. "How would you set a specific compiler version in an ASP.NET  5 web template" - you wouldn't, it's a configuration setting that you wouldn't 'set in a template'.

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow This question is 2 years old, has 7k views, a 5 upvoted answer and you want clarification? It's also out of date for today as ASP.NET 5 doesn't exist as it turned into ASP.NET Core, an old version of VS2105, and TS as well. Since we don't obsolete questions on SO, it's a snapshot in time. For what it's worth, there is no intellisense for TS versions in a XML file. The `--version` switch from the link emitted the compiler version. Lastly in ASP.NET 5 (at the time) the answer showed how MSBuild would use the values to determine to TS version. Most of this question is out of date.

Comment: @atconway the reason I'm asking for the question to be clarified is that it's difficult to find info on how VS determines the tools version to use, and although the OP relates to .NET 5 it has some useful info in the question that, if clarified, can still assist us in understanding the way this works :)  If you do want to clarify in the questions we can remove these comments as they're making the question less constructive.

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow This may help as it's _slightly_ newer: http://www.allenconway.net/2015/07/which-version-of-typescript-is.html and this is current for VS17 if using TypeScript via MSBuild: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Updating-TypeScript-in-Visual-Studio-2017 In a current project though, odds are one is controlling the TypeScript version via what's installed in `package.json` for TypeScript, and manipulating the TypeScript behavior via a `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Thanks Allen I already read your article and it helped me *a lot*! I've also seen that VS 2017 article however I'm using 2015

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears the TypeScript Tools (and corresponding compiler version) for ASP.NET 5 projects is set in the following files:

**TS 1.7:** C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion Condition="'$(TypeScriptToolsVersion)'==''">1.7</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <TscToolPath Condition="'$(TscToolPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript</TscToolPath>
    <TscToolExe Condition="'$(TscToolExe)' == ''">tsc.exe</TscToolExe>
    <TscYieldDuringToolExecution Condition="'$(TscYieldDuringToolExecution)' == ''">true</TscYieldDuringToolExecution>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**TS 1.8** C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\TypeScript

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion Condition="'$(TypeScriptToolsVersion)'==''">1.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <!-- Check the default folder for the nuget version of the installer first, if that exists we should use that. -->
    <TscToolPath Condition="'$(TscToolPath)' == '' AND Exists('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)tsc\tsc.exe') ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)tsc\</TscToolPath>
    <TscToolPath Condition="'$(TscToolPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript</TscToolPath>
    <TscToolExe Condition="'$(TscToolExe)' == ''">tsc.exe</TscToolExe>
    <TscYieldDuringToolExecution Condition="'$(TscYieldDuringToolExecution)' == ''">true</TscYieldDuringToolExecution>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Notice the 1st line in the configuration above has the value `1.7` for the TypeScript 1.7 compiler.

Comment: Install the latest version helps too :)

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2015 IDE will use TypeScript that is specified in PATH. If you can change it from TypeScript 1.7 to 1.8, it will work with ASP.NET 5 apps and other apps as will.

Don't need to use GULP, I hope your using VS IDE or its VS Code

*This approach will force all other applications to use TypeScript 1.8 only, however non ASP.NET 5 apps have entry in proj files.*

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with what is in the PATH variable for TypeScript. Is there any easy way to prove this works? (i.e. see some output during build of the targeted TS compiler path based on the modifications to the PATH variable, etc?)

Comment: it worked with Angular 2 Beta releases as my VS 2015 was having TS 1.5 when i installed it for first time.

Comment: In Windows 8 and older versions of TS the path variable was used (see my blog post: http://www.allenconway.net/2015/07/which-version-of-typescript-is.html) However, I checked and on Windows 10 with TS 1.8 there is no value defined in the PATH variable to the TS compiler. Are you sure about your answer?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no straight dependency on PATH and compiler version used by VS. In my case PATH contains way to 1.0 version, VS used 1.8 version and I need 2.1. So, my investigation going on

Comment: This isn't an answer. It's also full of extraneous information. You would just disable TypeScript compilation in VS and you'd be fine. Client-side is not server side. This has even less to do with gulp I'm nothing at all to do with vs code

Answer (score 3):

If you have the warning in Visual Studio:

> Warning       Your project does not specify a TypeScriptToolsVersion. The
>   latest available TypeScript compiler will be used (x.y). To remove
>   this warning, set TypeScriptToolsVersion to a specific version or
>   "Latest" to always select the latest compiler.

You can edit `TypeScript Tools Version` in your projects properties. You get this warning if you have the value for `TypeScript version` set to "None specified". Set it to "Use latest available" and the warning will go away.

[image]